# Allow a property to be null or a specified length

Tags: c#, data-annotations, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following definition.

```
[StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Mobile Last 4 must be 4 digits.")]
public string MobileLast4 { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to use `null` **or** if the field does have a value then it needs to be 4 characters in length.

The problem I'm running into is if the property is null the validation fails. Is there another attribute I should use or do I need to roll my own?

I suppose I could use a nullable int with a range attribute which would solve this problem, but I have other properties that don't accept numbers.

Comment: initialize with 4 null characters `"\0\0\0\0"`

Comment: The model binder sees this and escapes it so I end up actually getting that value. Besides a bit hackish don't you think?

Comment: yes very hackish it was just the first thing that came to mind when you need 4 chars that don't mean anything. and if the [stringlength] doesn't support it you'll have to find something else or hack it anyways

Comment: StringLength doesn't enforce validation : if value is left empty, it should not make validation fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [StringLength] attribute does not make the field required. If your validation fails it is not caused by the code that you have shown.

Comment: In support of andreas's answer-
According to the definition:
"You apply the StringLengthAttribute attribute to a property when you need to specify the number of characters allowed for the property. If the value of the property is null, the value will not fail validation for the StringLengthAttribute attribute. To validate that the value is not null, use the RequiredAttribute attribute."

Comment: Sigh, I feel dumb. Did a lot of debugging before I asked this and came to the conclusion that it was validating on null, but upon further debugging realized the string was coming through as `""`.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with EFCore.
I found that [StringLength] does indeed enforce not nullable. Maybe that is a change from the previous version, I am not sure, I did not check that.
However, in the documentation you see that it allows minimum length to be negative.

In order for that to work in my case I had to do these three things:

1. Add a negative number for minimum length.
2. Annotate with AllowNull attribute.
3. Make sure that the property is of a nullable value (string?)

   ```
       [StringLength(500,MinimumLength = -1)]
       [AllowNull]
       public string? Note { get; set; }
   ```

I hope that helps.